# How to remove field separators in awk when printing $0?

Tags: awk, field, separator

eg, each row of the file is  like :

```
1, 2, 3, 4,..., 1000
```

How can print out

```
1 2 3 4 ... 1000
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to delete the commas, you can use `tr`:

```
$ tr -d ',' <file
1 2 3 4 1000
```

If it is something more general, you can set `FS` and `OFS` (read [about FS and OFS](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)) in your begin block:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","; OFS=""} ...' file
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to set OFS (the output field separator).  Unfortunately, this has no effect unless you also modify the string, leading the rather cryptic:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' FS=, OFS=
```

Although, if you are happy with some additional space being added, you can leave OFS at its default value (a single space), and do:

```
awk -F, '{$1=$1}1'
```

and if you don't mind omitting blank lines in the output, you can simplify further to:

```
awk -F, '$1=$1'
```

Comment: WARNING: the last example omits more than just blank lines.  Any line in which the first field is 0 will also be filtered.  It is probably best to ignore the last simplification.

Answer (score 3):

You could also remove the field separators:

```
awk -F, '{gsub(FS,"")} 1'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried `awk -F, '{gsub(FS," ")} 1' ` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Set `FS` to the input field separators. Assigning to `$1` will then reformat the field using the output field separator, which defaults to space:

```
awk -F',\s*' '{$1 = $1; print}'
```

See the [GNU Awk Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Changing-Fields) for an explanation of `$1 = $1`

Comment: @Barmer, It is not working. I tested with this : `echo "1,2,3,4" | awk -F',' '{$0 = $0; print}'`.

Comment: @sat This works `echo "1,2,3,4" | awk -F',' '{$1=$1}1'`.  I guess its a typo from Barmar, needs to be `$1=$1` or `NF=NF` etc not `$0=$0`

Comment: @Jotne, Yes. But how? `$1` denoting the first field.

Comment: @sat `$1=$1` makes it rebuild the whole `$0`

Comment: @Jotne, Oh! yes. I got it!

Comment: @Barmar, +1 for the link.